# Java Reflection create POJO instance dynamically without POJO type

Tags: java, object, reflection, pojo

I have a response object say ResponseObj.

```
    public class ResponseObject {
       private String one;
       private String two;
       private String three;
       private String relationshipCd;
        private List listOfObjects;

        }
```

Coming from RMI. So this definition is untouchable ..

I want to create A pojo as a copy of this with only diff :

```
       instead of listOfObjects --> listOfSpecificType;
```

i Know specificType using Runtime info. 
Is there a reflection way of doing. All material I searched, wants to first create a POJOtype. Which I want to avoid. 
Let me know if any more clarification is needed. 
Thanks,
AM.

Comment: A List has no generic type at run time. It's just a List. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: Yeah I would like to traverse over the list and type cast to SpecificType. But that would be in the POJO which I want to create Dynamically

Comment: Casting to a subtype is only done explicitly where you know the type at compile time. Basically you have to explain what you are trying to do in more detail. Otherwise we can't help. The way you are thinking about your solution is not how Java works. You would use an interface or something instead.